# SQL: SUM the SUM of MAX values of results returned

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL statement produces the results listed below. Question is, how do I modify this statement to provide the sum total for each post_id? For example, post_id 1 should = 25, and post_id 2 should = 758.

```
SELECT t.post_id,
SUM(maxpostmetric) as sumvalue 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT post_metrics.post_id, 
    post_metrics.post_metric_type_id, 
    MAX( post_metrics.value ) maxpostmetric 
    FROM post_metrics 
    INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = post_metrics.post_id 
    WHERE posts.channel_id = 2268
    GROUP BY post_metrics.post_id, post_metrics.post_metric_type_id 
    ORDER BY post_metrics.id 
  )t 
INNER JOIN post_metric_types ON post_metric_types.id = t.post_metric_type_id 
GROUP BY t.post_id, t.post_metric_type_id
```

post_id:value;
1:0; 1:25; 1:0; 2:110; 2:588; 2:60;

1 = 25; 2 = 758.

Thanks

Comment: As a note, for proper formatting code should be indented with four spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're grouping by post_metric_type_id as well.  What is the purpose of the join and the grouping towards that field?  If you want your results to include that field, then add it to your select statement.

However, to get the SUM of the post_id's, remove that from your GROUP BY clause and you should be good to go.

```
SELECT t.post_id,
       SUM(maxpostmetric) as sumvalue 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT post_metrics.post_id, 
    post_metrics.post_metric_type_id, 
    MAX( post_metrics.value ) maxpostmetric 
    FROM post_metrics 
    INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = post_metrics.post_id 
    WHERE posts.channel_id = 2268
    GROUP BY post_metrics.post_id, post_metrics.post_metric_type_id 
    ORDER BY post_metrics.id 
  )t 
INNER JOIN post_metric_types ON post_metric_types.id = t.post_metric_type_id 
GROUP BY t.post_id
```

You may be able to remove your INNER JOIN as well -- depends on your needs.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to aggregate twice:

```
SELECT post_metrics.post_id, MAX( post_metrics.value ) maxpostmetric 
FROM post_metrics INNER JOIN
     posts
     ON posts.id = post_metrics.post_id 
WHERE posts.channel_id = 2268
GROUP BY post_metrics.post_id 
ORDER BY post_metrics.id
```

Comment: +1 -- wasn't even looking at the inner query, just the GROUP BY.  Good call.